# Gradient notworking after use path2D

Tags: javascript, matrix, canvas, path, 2d

I have a shape whose fillStyle is displayed by ctx.createLinearGradient.
I used to use ctx.beginPath and ctx.transform, and it worked fine.
But I want to do it with path2D, everything works fine but the gradient doesn't change.

I want the gradient to change along with path2D, scale or translate or rotate.

The main part of the code that I have used:

```js
const ctx = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('canvas')).getContext('2d')

// create a gradient
const gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(40, 0, 40, 80)

gradient.addColorStop(0, '#fff')
gradient.addColorStop(1, '#ff0000')
 
ctx.fillStyle = gradient

let translate = 60, scaleY = 1.1

//before change translate or scale
const p1 = new Path2D()

p1.arc(40, 40, 40, 0, 2 * Math.PI)
ctx.fill(p1)

//after change translate or scale
const p2 = new Path2D()

p2.addPath(p1, new DOMMatrix().translate(translate, translate).scale(1, scaleY));
ctx.fill(p2)
```

result:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the gradient is based on the canvas position. So either you translate the canvas or you create a new gradient based on the object
position.

```
const ctx = 
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('canvas'))
.getContext('2d')

// create a gradient
let gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(40, 0, 40, 80)

gradient.addColorStop(0, '#fff')
gradient.addColorStop(1, '#ff0000')

ctx.fillStyle = gradient

let translate = 60, scaleY = 1.1

//before change translate or scale
const p1 = new Path2D()

p1.arc(40, 40, 40, 0, 2 * Math.PI)
ctx.fill(p1)


//after change translate or scale
const p2 = new Path2D()

p2.addPath(p1, new DOMMatrix().translate(translate, translate).scale(1, 
scaleY));

gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(40+translate, 0+translate, 
40+translate, 80+translate)
gradient.addColorStop(0, '#fff')
gradient.addColorStop(1, '#ff0000')

ctx.fillStyle= gradient
ctx.fill(p2)
```